# How to implement "Search Previous" in a "Find Keyword" Windows Form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, search, match

I have a Log Window in my c# application. I have implemented a Find Keyword Feature in the form, it searches for all matching text in the `RichTextBox`.
Now I want to build a feature to search the Next and Previous matches throughout the RichTextBox.

The code for the `FindNext` is

```
try
{
    if (start_search_point < log_textbox.Text.Length && start_search_point != -1)
    {
        log_textbox.SelectionBackColor = highlight_all_color;
        log_textbox.Find(search_keyword, start_search_point, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
        log_textbox.SelectionBackColor = Color.Honeydew;

        if (start_search_point + search_keyword.Length < log_textbox.Text.Length)
            start_search_point = log_textbox.Text.IndexOf(search_keyword, start_search_point + search_keyword.Length);
        else
            start_search_point = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        start_search_point = 0;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MDIParent.thisMdiObj.txtLog.Invoke(new Action(() => MDIParent.thisMdiObj.txtLog.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + ex.Message + "=>" + ex.StackTrace.ToString() + Environment.NewLine)));
}
```

Can anyone help me with the `FindPrevious` part? I cannot figure out the logic for this one.

Answer (score 2):

How about creating MatchCollection and work with it?

```
MatchCollection matches = new Regex().Matches(search_keyword);

int currentIndex = 0;
```

And then just use currentIndex to get elements from your collection-

```
if(currentIndex > 0) --currentIndex;   // get previous search result
matches[currentIndex];
```

Example: 
[image]

Comment: what will `matches` contain? How will it get all the matching texts from the RichTextBox? @Fabjan

Comment: Matches is a collection with all found matches in text using pattern (just a keyword in your case) whereas single match or Matches[i] contains index position in text, where match was found, match text itself and some other information; To 'build a feature to search the Next and Previous' you just need to get them all in a collection and iterate through it.

Comment: Ok I got what you said. Let me try this method. But I cannot get 
`new Regex()`
It shows me an error 
`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Regex() ` is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: That's odd. Add a link to your reg ex library - using System.Text.RegularExpressions; (to your using statements) then just type MatchCollection matches = new Regex().Matches(search_keyword);

Comment: Yes I already added library reference `using System.Text.RegularExpressions` and that is why I can use `MatchCollection`. But not `Regex()`

Comment: Edited my answer and added example code, check it. You should pass your keyword to Regex ctor as parameter...

Comment: Hey thanks. Got It. Will let you know in a while as I test it.